# Adding a string into CEdit Text box instead of CCombobox

Tags: c++, string, combobox, mfc, edit

I currently have a combobox which displays a list of numbers which are retrieved elsewhere and stored into the variable "test". Every time another number is set for "test", that number will be added into the combobox list.

Is there a way where I can use a `CEdit` text box instead of a `CComboBox` to display my numbers?

This is how I have coded the combobox.

```
CComboBox *pCombobox = (CComboBox *) (GetDlgItem(IDC_ComboBox)); 

    strNumber.Format(_T("%d"),test);
    pCombobox->AddString(strNumber);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you have an appropriate edit control placed on your dialog with ID `IDC_Edit` for example, then get the existing string, append the new value to it, replace with new string.

```
CString text;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_Text, text);

if (text.IsEmpty())
    text.Format(_T("%d"), test);
else
    text.AppendFormat(_T(",%d"), test);

SetDlgItemText(IDC_Text, text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it tells me "No suitable conversion function from CString to int exists."

Comment: @m170115 Apologies, I had the syntax wrong. Rather use [`SetDlgItemInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa250326(v=vs.100)) directly.

Comment: This only sets 1 number. I have multiple numbers in my combobox. Is there a way to loop this like the `AddString` function so all my numbers are displayed?

Comment: Not clear. What do you want displayed? Multiple numbers adjacent to each other? Delimited how?

Comment: My combobox now has the numbers "1", "3", "4", "8" in its list. Every time another number is set to "test", that new number will be added to the list. Instead of having to dropdown the box to see all the numbers, I want to display it as "1,3,4,8..." in an edit text box.

Comment: In all these years I have never known about `AppendFormat`. That would have made my life easier. :)